# Heroku App accessible only from a few devices

Tags: heroku, dns

I deployed a web app to Heroku yesterday and it seemed to work if I access the URL from my machine. However I was not able to access from any other devices on the same AND different network.

I thought that maybe it's just my browser cached the website and in reality it's down.

Some of the web services that tell you if a specific URL is down or not report various results - some say it's down, some say it's up.

(Not sure if I can post links here!)

http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rock-paper-scissors-.herokuapp.com

https://currentlydown.com/rock-paper-scissors-.herokuapp.com

But then again - I am able to see it via https://browserling.com/

I thought that this might be due to cached DNS but 1 day is way too long and Android flushes DNS after every 10 minutes (as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

To see if your app on Heroku is running and responding to requests, use the Heroku Toolbelt command

```
heroku logs --tail
```

This command shows messages about the app status, i.e when it is up or if it crashes.

Having the logs running with the tail option show the requests as they happen.

If you are on the Heroku free plan, then your application will sleep after 30 minutes of activity.

Once sleeping, the next request to your Heroku app will automatically wake the app up.  The time taken to wake your app is largely dependant on how quickly your app starts, but should be a matter of seconds hopefully.

If an application is a little slow in starting, this could lead to a timeout and making it seem like you app is down.

If you do not see real-time log entries when trying to access your Heroku app from a particular device or network, my only thought is that there is some network policy or device blocking access to certain IP ranges (ie. Amazon Web Services).

Comment: But the app is working fine from selected networks. It is running and is healthy.

Comment: Some network administrators block IP address ranges.  If they have blocked access to Amazon web services, then you would not be able to access your app from that network.  I cannot think of any other reason why you cannot connect to your app from one network and not another at the same time.